# Fullcalendar: Seleccionar un día, quitando selección del dia anteriormente seleccionado

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Hola estoy trabajando con fullCalendar y tengo la siguiente duda,
Al seleccionar un día este queda marcado con un color diferente lo que esta muy bien, pero al seleccionar otro día del calendario, la selección anterior aun queda marcada.

¿Como puedo limpiar la selección anterior antes de marcar la actual?}

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var initialLocaleCode = 'es';

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            monthNamesShort: ['En', 'Fe', 'Ma', 'Ab', 'My', 'Jn', 'Jl', 'Ag', 'Sp', 'Oc', 'Nv', 'Dc'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
            dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
            buttonText: {
                month: "Mes", week: "Semana", day: "Día", list: "Agenda", prev: "Prev", next: "Sig", today: "hoy",
                weekHeader: "Sm"

            },
            weekHeader: "Sm",
            allDayHtml: "Todo<br/>el día",
            eventLimitText: "más",
            locale: initialLocaleCode,
            unselectAuto: true,
            selectable: false,
            buttonIcons: true,
            weekNumbers: true,
            navLinks: true,
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true,
                events: [
                <% obtenerFecha(); %>
            ],
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('hola has hecho clic en:' + date.format());

                $(this).css('background-color', '#ccffff');
            },
            color: 'yellow',
            textColor: 'black'


        })



    });
```

Comment: probaste con selectable: false..

Comment: revisa la [documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEvents) o si tienes un problema más especifico, agrega tu código

Comment: @Diego Avila, si ese atributo me permite bloquear la selección múltiple en el calendario pero no así la funcionalidad que busco. Probé con unselectAuto: false y true. Pero aun no doy en el clavo.

Answer (score 1):

Justo acabo de resolver esto que estas mencionando... lo que tienes que hacer es primero crear una variable:

```
var clickedRef = 0;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
```

En tu funcion dayClick es guardar en una variable

```
clickedRef  = $(this);
```

Con el objeto al que le estas dando <kbd>click</kbd>, para tener la información de ese objeto, al momento de hacer nuevamente <kbd>click</kbd> sobre otra fecha, entonces compare el objeto actual donde diste <kbd>click</kbd> con el objeto que tienes en la variable donde guardaste el objeto del <kbd>click</kbd> anterior, si no es el mismo entones puedes cambiar la propiedad background del objeto en la variable al color `default` y entonces cambiarle el color al objeto donde diste <kbd>click</kbd> y asignarlo ahora a la variable para su referencia.

Answer (score -1):

Sólo debes tener lo siguiente:

```
selectable: true,
unselectAuto: true,
```

La [propiedad `selectable`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectable) permite al usuario seleccionar varios días u horas pulsando o moviendo el ratón. Y la [propiedad `unselectAuto`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselectAuto) sirve para indicar si al pulsar en cualquier sitio de la página la selección debe limpiarse.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque suelen ser de poca ayuda para le usuario sin una explicación concreta de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir más detalles. Lee [answer] para más información.